# Hive Update query

Tags: hive

I have set all the parameters that needs to be set in hive for using transactions.

```
set hive.support.concurrency=true;
set hive.enforce.bucketing=true;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
set hive.compactor.initiator.on=true;
set hive.compactor.worker.threads=0;
```

Created table using below command

```
CREATE TABLE Employee(Emp_id int,name string,company string,Desg string) clustered by (Emp_id) into 5 buckets stored as orc TBLPROPERTIES(‘transactional’=’true’);
```

Inserted Data in hive table by using below command

```
INSERT INTO table Employee values(1,’Jigyasa’,’Infosys’,’Senior System Engineer’), (2,’Pooja’,’HCL’,’Consultant’), (3,’Ayush’,’Asia Tours an travels’,’Manager’), (4,’Tarun’,’Dell’,’Architect’), (5,’Namrata’,’Apolo’,’Doctor’);
```

But while Updating the data

```
Update Employee set Company=’Ganga Ram’ where Emp_id=5;
```

I am getting below error message

> FAILED:SemanticException [Error 10294]:Attempt to do Update or delete unsingtransaction manager thatdoes not support these operations.

Comment: Did you restart the hive after setting all these properties?

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Hive have a bug where
set hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager; at CLI doesn't take effect.

You can check this by running "set hive.txn.manager" which will print the current value.

The safest way is set this in hive-site.xml.